# How would I write this render method out in ReactJs, this is an interview question?

Tags: reactjs

Write a React render method for an array of people that when you click on a person's name you log their name.

Here is what I have tried:

```
class People extends React.Component {
  state = {
    people: [Andy, Matt, Elliot]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p> {this.state.people} </p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a click handler, so you wouldn't know what name a person was clicking. You are also not mapping over the values in the array using `.map()` You'd map over each state.people value, rendering a button that would manipulate the state object.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simplify this by using a *functional component*. As you're not doing anything with the state, you might as well define `people` as a constant.

```js
function People() {
  const people = ["Andy", "Matt", "Elliot"];
  const logPerson = (i) => console.log(people[i]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {people.map((person, index) => (
        <li onClick={() => logPerson(index)} key={index}>
          {person}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<People />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```